# Bookmarking ASP.NET search results using POST or GET?

Tags: asp.net, search, post, get, query-string

I need a little help understanding how HTML forms work. It is my understanding that forms that use GET as their method submit name/value pairs for all fields within the form tags of said submission. However, if you take a look at the follow example from Google (and I've seen this in many other places too) and only use one of the fields on the form:

http://books.google.co.uk/advanced_book_search

Rather than being sent to a page with a name/value pair for each field of the advanced search page you are taken to a much cleaner looking URL:

http://www.google.co.uk/search?tbo=p&tbm=bks&q=hitchiker&num=10

Despite all of the input fields on the advanced search page.

---

Onto my problem... My own advanced search page is quite large and at the moment is being POSTed to my search results page which is taking in the values and searching accordingly, no problems! However, I want my users to be able to bookmark/share their searches and in order to do this I need to have items being passed into the querystring but I don't want massive querystrings if I don't need them. If my user has only searched by a color for example then I want the URL to be something like search.aspx?color=red; If they're searching by color and size then search.aspx?color=red&size=large and so on. Is this possible?

To complicate things even further I'm using ASP.NET so it's not the easiest of things to create a form that uses GET though I do believe I have already found away around this.

If you can give any advice or a nudge in the right direction, then thank-you! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're suggesting should be easily possible if you conditionally check the querystring on the results page to ensure the key/value is there.

```
if(Request.QueryString["color"] != "")
{
    // Add color to the seach parameters
}
```

To create the GET request I would think you would need to POST back to your search form and redirect to the results form from there, dynamically adding key/values to the querystring as and when they are required. This [Post/Redirect/Get](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post/Redirect/Get) design pattern is typically used with web forms to help with book marking.

Comment: Is posting the page to itself and then redirecting bad practice? Will the user be able to see this redirect? A lot of flickering between clicking search and finally getting you your results could be a bit off-putting...

Comment: @sgtbeardy - i've added an edit to show the design pattern this is based on which is used a lot with asp.net web forms and shouldn't cause any 'flickering'. As the postback method just needs to collate the user input into a querystring and then redirect I wouldn't imaging you will see any discernable delay in the request.

Comment: @Andy - your code will currently not compile as your have used a close parenthesis instead of square bracket.

Comment: @Andy Thank-you for your help, I'll give it a go! I would've thought because the page is posting to itself (one page refresh) and then that page is redirecting to the search results page (a second page refresh) you'd get a bit of screen refresh flickering and a longer wait than a signle redirect. But yes, I'll have a crack and see what happens! :)

Comment: @sgtbeardy - once the postback method completes it sends back a redirect to the client to get the url with the querystring it has generated. As there is no content (html or other) to write to the client within this call there will be no flicker in the browser. Overall it should appear fairly seamless unless the postback method that is called when the search page is submitted takes a very long time to complete.

Comment: @Smirking -fixed the typo, hopefully this didn't hide the intent.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to share bookmarked searches between users, then you'll have to share the name/value querystring options in the posted URL.  It sounds like you don't want to include the pair if one wasn't specified.  That's easy, just dynamically build a querystring for pairs that the user HAS provided input for.  So, when processing, loop through all input controls, and if a value was provided, append it to the querystring, or not.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Are you talking about posting the advanced search to itself, building a querystring based on what has been filled in and then redirecting to my search.aspx page with those values?